# TUICandidateView：unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, react-native

My project is a `react-native` project.

Crash information as below:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TUICandidateView collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1056236f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1975f3ab0 0x19730d028 0x1974f1f10 0x19b708a80 0x1975f8254 0x1975fa3f0 0x19af06fbc 0x19af2f288 0x19b70728c 0x19b707388 0x19b70728c 0x19b707388 0x19b7159c0 0x19b716cb0 0x19b6f26d8 0x19b76cd2c 0x19b76f2e4 0x19b768468 0x19756f24c 0x19756f1a0 0x19756e90c 0x1975697d8 0x197569084 0x1a17b7534 0x19b6d9698 0x102f2b0dc 0x1973e8e18)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

react-native version: 0.55.4

Xcode version: 11.3

iOS version: 13

1. I tried on the simulator and my iPhone devices. both are crashed.
2. I have searched for much-related information about `TUICandidateView` on google, but it gives me nothing.

If you have any information about it. please let me know.

Thanks in advance

---

**Finally, I solved it.**

The reason why my app crashed is I add some other sensitive SDK to my project. and It will monitor my code and raise an exception. So I remove the SDK and no more crash.

Comment: Glad the issue is resolved. Please post the answer as an 'answer' so that it'll also help someone else having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem.

I tried this in a new project with the same react-native version. I found that it's ok, no crash.

So I think it must be some other code has conflicts with my project.

I checked my code and found that there is a monitor SDK in my project, and it will monitor my code. and if I input Chinese(Some other language maybe, except English), it will crash, I do not know why for now.

So I think the SDK has conflicts with iOS 13 (I only test iOS 13), but in iOS 10, it works. So I `removed this SDK` and there is no crash anymore.
Hope that this can help you.